# How do I get the entryComponents dynamically using import() method of Typescript 2.4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

`Typescript 2.4` introduce `[import()][1]` method to load modules dynamically. I am trying to load components dynamically using the following mentioned procedure https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader where we need to mention `entryComponents` in the module.
I am able to load all component modules dynamically using `import()` method in the AppModule but I am not able to get `entryComponents` of the modules. For example,
I have a component and its module

data-widget.component:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'data-widget',
   templateUrl: 'data-widget.component.html'
   })
   export class DataWidget{}
```

and
data-widget.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ...,
  declarations: [DataWidget],
  exports: [DataWidget],    
  providers:    [],
   entryComponents: [DataWidget]               
})
export class DataWidgetModule {
    constructor(private widgetService: widgetService) {
      widgetService.register('weather', DataWidget);   
    }        
 }
```

I am now able to load that module dynamically using `import()` method in the following way

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ...,
  declarations: [],
  exports: [],    
  providers:    []
 
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private apiService: apiService) {
      apiService.getMoudleUrls().subscribe( data=>{
           import(''+data); //e.g './data-widget/data-widget.module'    
      },
      error=>{});
    }        
 }
```

In AppModule module the DataWidgetModule loaded in Webpack dynamically.Now I am trying to load DataWidget Component dynamically. You can see that I have register the component in `DataWidgetModule` using `widgetService`. But this function was not called during module loading as well as the entryComponents are also not loaded. So, when I tried to load the component using the following way which I have mentioned above

`this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(widgetService.getRegisteredWidget());`

then I am getting error as `entryComponents` are not loaded in @ngModule. How can I load the entryComponents and register the components for dynamic load? It will be very helpful to get a solution for it. Thank you.

Comment: Did u ever manage to make this work? In AngularJS requirejs was doing great job but now we are missing this possibility as app need to know about every model prior compilation and we can not develop modules without adding those to main app module :(.

Comment: This link https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-tips-dynamic-module-imports-with-the-angular-cli will give an idea for dynamic module import. I have tried this to load modules dynamically but facing problem to generate dynamic components. Whenever I directly import modules then the entryComponents are working but when I tried the import() method then it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution for it. The following code will help you to solve this problem.

```
export class DynamicComponent {    
    injector: Injector;
    compiler: Compiler;
    @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) 
    container: ViewContainerRef; 
    componentRef: any; 

    constructor(private compFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, injector: Injector,
        private apiService: apiService) {

        this.injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(COMPILER_PROVIDERS, injector);
        this.compiler = this.injector.get(Compiler);
    }
    addWidget(){

      apiService.getMoudleUrls().subscribe( module_url=>{
        let module_= import(module_url); //e.g './data-widget/data-widget.module'    
        module_.then(module_data =>{

        const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( module_data );
        let moduleFactories = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(module_data[keys[1]]);
        const moduleRef = moduleFactories.ngModuleFactory.create(this.injector);
        const componentFactory = moduleFactories.componentFactories
         .find(e => e.selector === 'data-widget'); // find the entry component using selector       
        this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory, null, moduleRef.injector);

        const newItem: WidgetComponent = this.componentRef.instance; 
   },
  error=>{});
 }
}
```

Comment: this answer might be deprecated as Angular 5 moved away from reflect injector and moved toward staticinjector.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the right topic, but I had a similar problem and found a little hacky solution.

The problem was that I wanted to use the entry components of a new compiled module inside the parent module. The entry components of the loaded and compiled module are present only in the compiled module so I had to add them to the parent module entry components.

Just add the entry components factories to the parent component factories.

```
const resolver = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver;

resolver._factories.forEach(function (value, key) {
   resolver._parent._factories.set(key, value);
});
```

In my case I had only a few components and entry components in the loaded module so it is no overhead to merge them with the parent component factories. For larger loaded modules I think it would be good to only merge the entry components...